# List.Orderby in C# first orderby numbers that are even asc then same number that are odd decending

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a List that is called myDeliverable

`myDeliverable` contains an object called `Buyer`. `Buyer` has an `string street` and a `int housenumber`

Now I want to order first by street alphabetically, then by the house numbers that are even ascending from 0,1,2,3.n and then the housenumbers that are odd decending. So the output should be something like:

```
AAstreet 2
AAstreet 10
AAstreet 12
AAstreet 20
AAstreet 13
AAstreet 9
AAstreet 1
BAstreet 4
BAstreet 8
BAstreet 3
(...)
```

So I wrote the follwing:

```
    myDeliverables = myDeliverables
        .OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber).Where(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 == 0) // even
        .ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber).Where(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 != 0) // odd
        .ToList();
```

VS givens me an error `.ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber` saying that something does not have a `.ThenBy` method. I assume I have to do where in the end or something. Not sure how to do this, haven't used LINQ before.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that when you call `.Where` it's actually filtering elements of the list -- `.Where(x.Buyer.HouseNumber % 2 == 0)` would leave you with only even house numbers. It's throwing a compile-time error on `.ThenBy` because Linq has in a sense 'forgotten' that the list was sorted. But even if that wasn't the case, `.Where(x.Buyer.HouseNumber % 2 != 0)` would filter *out* even house numbers. So even if your sorting worked, you'd be left with an empty list.

You first need to sort by the parity of the number (whether it is even or odd), *then* by the number itself. You can use of the parity to decide whether to sort ascending or descending.

Try this:

```
myDeliverables = myDeliverables
    .OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2)  // parity
    .ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 == 0 
               ? x.Buyer.Housenumber       // evens ascending
               : -x.Buyer.Housenumber)     // odds descending
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but wonder, why not?

            `myDeliverables = myDeliverables
                .OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 == 0)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 != 0)
                .ToList();`

It's the same right?

Comment: @ganjan It's not the same. **1)** `.ThenBy(x.Buyer.Housenumber % 2 == 0)` will sort by parity, but the odd numbers first (because false < true when sorting) **2)** the second `.ThenBy` will have no effect because it's already ordered by parity and **3)** it never actually sorts the house numbers.